# Catch Referer of a User

Tags: php, functional-programming, concept

Consider, I am on a website `webone.com/index.php?id=12` and there is a another website posted `webtwo.com/visit.php` by another user (me in this case). If someone clicks on the `webtwo.com/visitor.php`, I want the visitor Referer which is `webone.com/index.php?id=2` in this case.

Note: I am not getting this using PHP global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Pass it through a GET parameter. It's either that or using the HTTP header.

Comment: The first website is not mine.

Comment: Then you can't know if the first website doesn't want you to know.